# I'm having issues passing data to a second view from a UITableView

Tags: ios, sqlite, uitableview, segue

I'm having trouble sending data to a different view using the "prepareForSegue"  method…

I have a tableview that's populated with results from an sqlite query. When I tap on one of table cells it directs me to another view where I have a label that will tell me the ID and Name of the

I have a NSString that holds the value of an ID from an SQLite datasource. I want to pass that id to the second view of my app, to use it to grab information from the sqlite datasource that's based off that id.

Now I've written code where it'll pass information from one view to the other… but for some reason the information is "off count". Here's what I mean, I have a list of 3 mountain areas: Deception, Far Side, and Mt. Washington (listed in a tableview on the first view). When I click on Mt. Washington, it'll go to the second view, and the label that I have setup to tell me the name of the selected cell…. is blank. I hit back button on the navigation bar, and tap Mt. Washington again, and this time the label displays the name of "Mt. Washington". Now when I go back and click on "Far Side", the label displays "Mt. Washington". When I go back and click on "Far Side" again, The label changes to "Far Side". Hopefully that makes sense.

Does any one know how to fix the problem?
Here's the code I have:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"areaIDpush"]){
      RockViewController *rockRoutes = [segue destinationViewController];
      rockRoutes.rockID = areaID_fk;
      rockRoutes.rockName = areaName_fk;
    }
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   areaID_fk = cell.detailTextLabel.text;
   areaName_fk = cell.textLabel.text;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[areaIDLabel setText:rockID];
[areaNameLabel setText:rockName];
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
```

}

Hopefully that'll help you see where I'm running into problems... any kind of help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: areaID_fk = cell.detailTextLabel.text;// its wrong
areaName_fk = cell.textLabel.text;//its wrong Check below i have added code to assign from database..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sent my code to a buddy, and he helped me realize what was going wrong.

Here's the right code:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
        if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"areaIDpush"]){
        RockViewController *rockRoutes = [segue destinationViewController];
        rockRoutes.rockID = areaID_fk;
        rockRoutes.rockName = areaName_fk;

        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow];
        rockRoutes.rockName = cell.textLabel.text;
        rockRoutes.rockID = cell.detailTextLabel.text;
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the name and ID in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`: method....First you have initialize two variables for both name and ID in that second view.and pass the value from ur first view like

```
secondview.variable1=ID;
secondview.variable2=name;
```

in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: You are using a bad(or) duplicate code....you have to pass ur value only on didselect method.so that simulator understands to pass the values while user tap a cell and get a link to second view with values

Comment: Thanks for your response!!! A little confused with the reply though... :) So in my AreasViewContoller.m file, I have the variables areaID_fk and areaName_fk initialized and assigned with the selected values in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. AreasViewController.m:
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; areaID_fk = cell.detailTextLabel.text; areaName_fk = cell.textLabel.text;}

Comment: Where do I add the: "secondview.variable1=ID; secondview.variable2=name;" that you suggested? in the same method?

Comment: add this code in didSelect method itself...pass the number also.so the next view can identify from which row the values from...

Comment: secondview.variable1=sqliteDB.ID;      //SqliteDB-its sqlite Database name.